# SQL Full Join, not returning all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I’m trying to return a full list of categories and any associated products (note I need to bring back all categories even if there are no products)

technet says: ‘to retain the nonmatching information by including nonmatching rows in the results of a join, use a full outer join.’

so I thought the below query would do the trick:

```
Select * from category 
full outer join product
on category.categoryName = product.categoryName
```

Category Table

```
ID  categoryName
1   Plumbing
2   Electrics
3   Roofing
```

Product Table (note this actually has 15 additional columns)

```
ID  productName categoryName
1    pipe        plumbing
2    plug         Electrics
3    Drill  
4    washer        plumbing
```

wanted results set:

```
ID  categoryName    productName
1   Plumbing    pipe
2   Electrics   plug
3   Roofing     Null
4   Plumbing    washer
```

current results

```
ID  categoryName    productName
1   Plumbing    Null
2   Electrics   Null
3   Roofing         Null
```

in the actual data there are 20 categories and I always get 20 rows back, I effectively get the category table with the columns from the product table on the right but all null values.

Comment: do you have any `where` conditions on your query?

Comment: no just the query as above

Comment: what collation do you have on your database? which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Is categoryName for `3    Drill` actually an empty string? (if so, why not NULL?)

Comment: I fail to reproduce the current results you claim to have with the sample data you provided: [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/865e3/2)

Comment: great link i didn't know sqlfiddle exsisted.. Thanks,

OK so that means the query is fine, and it could be an environmental issue?

Comment: btw, check also the upper/lower case :) ('Plumbing' != 'plumbing' )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am strongly under the impression that the values inside `categoryName` from `Category Table` and `categoryName` from `Product Table` are not consistent.

I could not explain this otherwise right now, because I tried to reproduce your issue using the sample values you provided. (see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/865e3/2)).

I'd recommend you run a select against both to see whether there are additional `whitespaces` that we don't see at first glance here.

Something like

`SELECT REPLACE(categoryName, ' ', '-') FROM Category` and

`SELECT REPLACE(categoryName, ' ', '-') FROM Product` to make those visible.

EDIT: Ah, did not think of it at first, but the obvious way to check whether two fields have the same length would of course be `DATALENGTH` (`SELECT DATALENGTH(categoryName) FROM Category--/Product` )

Answer (score -1):

Try,

Your **Product Table Dont't have category** But you matching  **product.category**

```
on category.categoryName = product.categoryName
```

Comment: though that is true, it does not answer the question/explain the results

Comment: I understand you do not have enough reputation to comment already, so you write a `fake answer`, which IMHO is fine, but since the typo you mentioned has been accounted for you should delete your answer now to avoid getting downvoted into oblivion ;)